# "extract" package causes unfinished group

Tags: grouping, extract

I've noticed errors like this when using the [`extract` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/extract?lang=en):

```
(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)

### semi simple group (level 1) entered at line 5 (\begingroup)
```

This seems to happen even with an almost empty document, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[generate=foo.ext]{extract}

\begin{document}
Hello!
\end{document}
```

Would anyone have an idea why `extract` (extract 2019/09/18 v1.9a) is causing that error, and how to fix it?

Comment: Just wondering if you read the manual, e.g. example on p.3 https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/extract/extract.pdf ? At a glance your code doesn't seem to be complete for the extract environment.

Comment: the package redefines \begin and \end and completly breaks the new hook system of LaTeX, I wouldn't use it.

Comment: @MS-SPO: I reduced this from a complete (and working-in-production) setup. I figured I should remove as much as possible while still retaining the error -- should the package be expected to cause this error _unless_ it was more fully configured?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Interesting! Have you got an alternative in mind by any chance?

Comment: No. Write the author. He probably can use the new hooks instead of destroying them, or he could ask for real interfaces instead of redefining internal commands.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: OK! Is the "new hook system" well-enough known that the author will know what we're referring to?

Comment: I think he will manage.

Answer (score 5):

extract was created in 2005, long before any hook system was even discussed. So the new LaTeX destroyed the extract package.

As I am not using LaTeX anymore for a long time, and I have no clue about the changes in LaTeX that destroyed extract, it will probably a better idea if someone else has a look at the problem. Ulrike Fisher? I can integrate the required changes in the package and post it to CTAN.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I understand that it may not be something you're keen on dealing with if you've moved on, so I really appreciate it.

@UlrikeFischer: If you have any pointers or advice, I could try and look into this, too. I don't know anything about the new hooks yet, but I could give it a try.

Comment: @KerrekSB sorry I never got a ping from your comment. If you want to learn something about the new hooks, read the documentation `texdoc lthooks-doc.pdf` should give it too you.